# Sensitivity analysis: How do I generate multiple dataset and run bayesian regression analysis on each of the dataset?

Tags: r, regression, lapply, bayesian, rjags

Here is my original model.

```
  library(rjags)
  library(R2jags)
  cat("model{
for(i in 1 :N){
y[i] ~ dnorm(theta[i],tau)
theta[i] <- beta[1] + beta[2]*x1[i] + beta[3]*x2[i]
}
for(j in 1:3){
beta[j] ~ dnorm(0,0.001)}
sigma ~ dgamma(0.001,0.001)
tau <- pow(sigma,-2)
    }",file="m1.txt")

set.seed(123)
dd <- data.frame(y=rnorm(20,0,1),
            v=sample(seq(0, 50, by=5),size=20,replace = T),
            m=sample(seq(2,48,by=3),size=20,replace = T))
d <- with(dd,list(N=length(y),y=y,x1=v,x2=m))

 model1 <- jags(data=d,inits=NULL,
               parameters.to.save=c("beta","tau"),
               n.chains=3,n.iter=10000,n.burnin=5000,n.thin=10,
               model.file="m1.txt")
```

I am trying to do sensitivity analysis using the regression model above. I have two independent variables v and m.

Where v takes value between 0 and 50, m takes value between 2 and 48

I want to generate new datasets with a unit increment of v and m such that:

dataset 1: i set v =0 and m=2

dataset 2: v = 1 and m= 2

.          .        .

.          .        .

.          .        .

dataset 51: v =51 and m=2

dataset 52: v=0 and m=3

dataset 53: v = 1 and m= 3

.          .        .

.          .        .

.          .        .

dataset 102: v =51 and m=3

.          .        .

.          .        .

.          .        .

dataset 153: v =0 and m=4

.          .        .

.          .        .

.          .        .

dataset 2448: v =51 and m=48
NB: The dataset should have 20 rows each and y should be a random number.

I will then use the 2000 plus dataset and the coefficients of beta[s] to predict ys so for each dataset I should predict 20 values of y. I have a benchmark value for y. So in each predicted value I will plot number the number of y that meets the benchmark value for each combination of v and m values.

Please how do I incorporate the above into it my original model?

Comment: Do you want e.g. a dataset 1 with 20 rows in  which  y is a random number and two other columns v and m  which are just 0 and 2 repeated 20 times, respectively?

Comment: @ yes the data set will have 20 rows each

Answer (score 0):

This is how to create data frames with all possible combinations of m and v:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data_frames <-
  expand_grid(
  v = seq(0, 50, by = 5),
  m = seq(2, 48, by = 3)
) %>%
  mutate(
    data = v %>% map2(m, ~ {
      data.frame(
        y = rnorm(20, 0, 1),
        v = .x,
        m = .y
      )
    })
  )
data_frames
#> # A tibble: 176 x 3
#>        v     m data         
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <list>       
#>  1     0     2 <df [20 × 3]>
#>  2     0     5 <df [20 × 3]>
#>  3     0     8 <df [20 × 3]>
#>  4     0    11 <df [20 × 3]>
#>  5     0    14 <df [20 × 3]>
#>  6     0    17 <df [20 × 3]>
#>  7     0    20 <df [20 × 3]>
#>  8     0    23 <df [20 × 3]>
#>  9     0    26 <df [20 × 3]>
#> 10     0    29 <df [20 × 3]>
#> # … with 166 more rows
data_frames$data[[1]]
#>              y v m
#> 1   0.04844153 0 2
#> 2  -0.39136686 0 2
#> 3  -1.20848091 0 2
#> 4  -0.52041488 0 2
#> 5  -1.97372954 0 2
#> 6  -0.49918332 0 2
#> 7  -0.65153827 0 2
#> 8   0.61465528 0 2
#> 9  -0.63446048 0 2
#> 10  1.67354439 0 2
#> 11  0.31279567 0 2
#> 12  0.10422302 0 2
#> 13  0.14853823 0 2
#> 14 -0.60451679 0 2
#> 15  1.79470355 0 2
#> 16  0.39043583 0 2
#> 17 -0.12879205 0 2
#> 18 -0.26973252 0 2
#> 19 -2.32701504 0 2
#> 20 -0.84522199 0 2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks. I will try and see how to incorporate it into my model